# Sort list to make letters come before digits in any position

Tags: python, list, sorting

Say I have the following list:

```
l = ['erget', 'a1', 'm1', 'aa', 'ae', 'mea', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'm2', 'me2', 'mei']
```

When using `sorted()` over lists of strings that also contain digits, the digits come before the letters, so in this case it would yield:

```
sorted(l)
['a1', 'aa', 'ae', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'erget', 'm1', 'm2', 'me2', 'mea', 'mei']
```

I've seen some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373842/sorting-python-list-to-make-letters-come-before-numbers) on how to make letters appear before digits, but only for a single digit or letter. Is it possible to also do it using some `key` in `sorted()` when the digit can be anywhere in the string? So expected output:

```
['aa', 'ae', 'a1', 'erget', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'mea', 'mei', 'me2', 'm1', 'm2']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a list of tuples as a custom key:

```
L = ['erget', 'a1', 'm1', 'aa', 'ae', 'mea', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'm2', 'me2', 'mei']
res = sorted(L, key=lambda x: [(i.isdigit(), i) for i in x])

# ['aa', 'ae', 'a1', 'erget', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'mea', 'mei', 'me2', 'm1', 'm2']
```

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that I also need them ordered by length, but just did so working from your solution using `sorted(l, key=lambda x:  [len(x)] + [(i.isdigit(), i) for i in x])`. Nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a key function that iterates through each character of a given string and prepends `'z'` to those that are digits so that they are sorted after alphabets:

```
l = ['erget', 'a1', 'm1', 'aa', 'ae', 'mea', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'm2', 'me2', 'mei']
sorted(l, key=lambda s: ['z' + c if c.isdigit() else c for c in s])
```

This returns:

```
['aa', 'ae', 'a1', 'erget', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'mea', 'mei', 'me2', 'm1', 'm2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack:

```
>>> l = ['erget', 'a1', 'm1', 'aa', 'ae', 'mea', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'm2', 'me2', 'mei']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda a: [ord(c) if ord(c) > 57 else ord(c) + 100 for c in a])
['aa', 'ae', 'a1', 'erget', 'erge4', 'erge7', 'mea', 'mei', 'me2', 'm1', 'm2']
```