# How to sort a list that has both integers and letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am creating a program that sorts the user's input in ascending and descending order. What I have tried below was only working with integers, I tried to use `str` but only the letters are sorted.

```
a = input("Enter your list with space:")
b = list(map(int, a.split()))

print("Original List:", b)

print("Sorted Ascending Order:")
print (sorted(b))

print("Sorted Descending Order:")
print(sorted(b, reverse=True))
```

If I would enter `10 2 3`, the result would be `[2, 3, 10]` and `[10, 3, 2]`.
What I want is to sort something like `10 a 2 c` that would result to `[a, c, 2, 10]` and `[10, 2, c, a]`.

I would like anyone to guide me on what should I use/add or change.

Actually, what I want to ask is  on how could I sort a list with numbers and letters. I have tried some code before but it would read 10 as 1 and 0. Some of it would only sort the letters and not the numbers.

Comment: Write a [custom sort method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373842/sorting-python-list-to-make-letters-come-before-numbers) that distinguishes between numbers and letters, values letters lower than numbers, and otherwise sorts normally within each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom comparator that first sorts by `isinstance` to prioritize `int` over `str`, then defer to the value itself.

```
>>> b = [10, 'a', 2, 'c']
>>> sorted(b, key=lambda i: (isinstance(i, int), i), reverse=True)
[10, 2, 'c', 'a']
>>> sorted(b, key=lambda i: (isinstance(i, int), i))
['a', 'c', 2, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to convert only those values to integers that are actually valid integers.

```
user_in = input("Enter your list with spaces: ")
user_list = user_in.split()
for i, u in enumerate(user_list):
    try:
        # Try to replace the string with the integer
        user_list[i] = int(u)
    except ValueError:
        # ValueError happened. Invalid integer. Must be a letter
        pass
```

With this, you now have a list that contains strings and integers.

```
print(user_list)
# Output:
[10, 'a', 2, 'c']
```

Next, you need to tell Python how to compare a letter with a number, because Python has no way of doing that out of the box. However, we can use the `key` argument of the `sorted()` function to tell Python to pass each item to a function, and use its return value as the value to sort by. Finally, we can leverage the fact that Python can sort tuples, and that tuples are sorted by their first element, then by their second element, and so on. If we return a tuple containing a boolean (is this item an integer?) and the item itself, then we can ensure all strings are sorted before integers in ascending order.

```
def keyfunc(item):
    is_int = isinstance(item, int)
    return (is_int, item)
sorted_list = sorted(user_list, key=keyfunc)

print(sorted_list)
# Output: 
['a', 'c', 2, 10]
```

Of course, you could condense all this down to a lambda function like [Cory's answer](/a/67077934/843953), but I have included the verbose approach for clarity.